# Expected time of drawing all types of coins from a large pile

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I've been working on the following question but am uncertain of how to solve it

Consider an infinitely large pile of coins. Each coin has a number
{1, 2, . . . , n} written on it, and these numbers appear in equal propor-
tions in the pile. Suppose that you keep drawing coins from this pile
until the first time, T , that you have at least one coin of each number
{1, 2, . . . , n}. Find the expected value of T.

Comment: This link may provide some assistance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i(k):=\mathbb{P}\{ i^{th} \mbox{ type of coin is drawn for the first time on the }k^{th} \mbox{draw} \}$.  This random variable follows a geometric distribution with parameter $p=\frac{1}{n}$.
Let $T:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ then:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[T]=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\sum_{i=1}^n n = n^2.  
\end{equation}

Comment: I don't think this is right unless the process the OP is thinking of requires you first to draw a specimen of coin $1$ before you start looking for coin $2$, draw a specimen of coin $2$ before you start looking for coin $3$, etc.